# How to perform programmatic `transform` after animating when `fill` is "forwards"

Tags: javascript, css-animations

After animating an element using the Animation API I am unable to perform another `transform` if the `animation-fill-mode` property is set to true.

Consider the following script:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#box');

document.querySelector("#translate").addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)"
})

document.querySelector("#animate").addEventListener('click', () => {
  var animation = elem.animate({
    opacity: [0.5, 1],
    transform: ['translateX(0)', 'translateX(25px)'],
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    iterations: 1,
    // Change this value to "auto" or "none" for expected behavior
    fill: "forwards"
  });
})
```

If clicking on the `#animate` button I would expect to see the animation perform. This does happen correctly. After the animation is complete and the element is 25px more to the right, the `#translate` (would be better named `#transform`) button no longer performs the rotation when clicked.

It does correctly rotate the element if the `fill` property is not "forwards" or "both".

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/yayebiceha/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I don't know if it supposed to, but as it is now, it doesn't touch the css. So I would guess the animation overwrite the css. (and 'fill' just do what it should do)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that is a hack. I'll post it here but ideally, there exists a solution that is not this.

It seems as though cancelling the animation will "unlock" the element to be transformed again.

```
const elem = document.querySelector('#box');

document.querySelector('#translate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem.style.transform = elem.style.transform + ' rotate(45deg)';
});

document.querySelector('#animate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const animationDuration = 500;
  const targetTranslation = 'translateX(25px)';

  const animation = elem.animate({
    transform: ['translateX(0)', targetTranslation],
  }, {
    duration: animationDuration,
    iterations: 1,
    // Change this value to "auto" or "none" for expected behavior
    fill: 'forwards'
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    animation.cancel();
    elem.style.transform = targetTranslation;
  }, animationDuration);
});
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/xejafigoto/1/edit?html,js,output)